# Querying an entire specific array inside another array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDB collection, called myCollection, and inside myCollection there is a structure like this:

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "posts": [
       [
          {
             "id": "0.0",
             "name": "john",
             "message": "hello"
          },
          {
             "id": "0.1",
             "name": "jane",
             "message": "good morning"
          },
          {
             "id": "0.2",
             "name": "josh",
             "message": "good evening"
          }
       ],
       [
          {
             "id": "1.0",
             "name": "mark",
             "message": "good lunch"
          }
       ],
       [
          {
             "id": "2.0",
             "name": "john",
             "message": "bye bye"
          },
          {
             "id": "2.1",
             "name": "mark",
             "message": "hi"
          }
       ]
    ]
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can query this structure to obtain the ENTIRE array that contains a specific object?
For example, launching a query around this specific object:

```
{
    "id": "2.0",
    "name": "john",
    "message": "bye bye"
}
```

I would to obtain this entire array:

```
       [
          {
             "id": "2.0",
             "name": "john",
             "message": "bye bye"
          },
          {
             "id": "2.1",
             "name": "mark",
             "message": "hi"
          }
       ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below query is help :

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
  { $match : { "id": 1234}},
  { $unwind  : '$posts'},
  {$match : {
        'posts' : { $elemMatch : { 'id' : '2.0',name : 'john'}} 
     }
  },
  { $unwind : '$posts'},
  { $project : {
      'id' : '$posts.id',
      name : '$posts.name',
      message :'$posts.message',
      _id : 0
     }
  }
])
```

Comment: thank you for your reply!  myCollection also contains other documents besides the one with "id":"1234". So, how can I specify inside the query that you have suggested me that I want to search the array that contains the { 'id' : '2.0',name : 'john'} object only inside the document with "id":"1234"?

Comment: Answer Updated! check if you are passing "1234" or 1234.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work .. :( The query does not return the array [ { "id": "2.0",  "name": "john", "message": "bye bye" }, {  "id": "2.1", "name": "mark", "message": "hi" } ] ..... :(

Comment: In particular, with the query that you have suggested me, I retrive the whole structure inside the collection. Can you tell me how I can get only the entire array [ { "id": "2.0", "name": "john", "message": "bye bye" }, { "id": "2.1", "name": "mark", "message": "hi" } ] ?

Comment: Thank you very much @the_mahasagar for you help. Your solution works correctly and is exactly what I needed!